# Django Tastypie 0.9.13-beta: resource always return status_code 200

Tags: python, django, tastypie

I've been working on API using `Django` and `Tastypie` of version `django-tastypie==0.9.13-beta` and in test cases when I expect `bad request` response with 400 or 401 and it always returns `http ok` 200 response. What can cause this problem?

#### User resource

```
class UserAuthentication(ApiKeyAuthentication):
    def __init__(self, no_auth, full_auth, require_active=True):
        super(Authentication, self).__init__()
        self.no_auth = no_auth
        self.full_auth = full_auth

    def is_authenticated(self, request, **kwargs):
        if request.method not in self.no_auth:
            return super(UserAuthentication, self).is_authenticated(request, **kwargs)

        return True


class UsersResource(MyModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = User.objects.all()
        allowed_methods = ['post']
        detail_allowed_methods = ['put']
        fields = ['id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email']
        validation = UserValidation()
        always_return_data = True
        authorization = UserAuthorization()
        authentication = UserAuthentication(no_auth=['GET', 'POST'], full_auth=['PUT'])
```

#### Small part of tests

```
def test_login_unsuccessful_wrong_email(self):
    post_data = {
        "user": {
            "email": 'wrong@email.com',  # so email is wrong
            "password": self.user_password
        }
    }

    response = self.api_client.post('/api/v1/login/', data=post_data)

    self.assertHttpBadRequest(response)    # At this place I expect 400 status code
```

#### Test failure traceback

```
FAIL: test_login_unsuccessful_wrong_email (api.v1.tests.UsersLoginResourceTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/sultan/.virtualenvs/myenv/myproject/api/v1/tests.py", line 458, in test_login_unsuccessful_wrong_email
    self.assertHttpBadRequest(response)
  File "/Users/sultan/.virtualenvs/myenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_tastypie-0.9.13_beta-py2.7.egg/tastypie/test.py", line 346, in assertHttpBadRequest
    return self.assertEqual(resp.status_code, 400)
AssertionError: 200 != 400
```

Thanks.

Comment: I think you would only get 400 if your request was actually invalid. Since your request is valid and only the information delivered with that request is wrong (wrong != invalid) you still get 200. You would need to adapt the server side to check for validity of emails and return 400 code if necessary.

Comment: fix the syntax error: `'wrong@email.com` should be `'wrong@email.com'`

Comment: @karthikr in the code its ok :)

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way to do that is first.

create exception class:

```
class HTTPError(Exception):
    def __init__(self, code, msg):
        Exception.__init__(self, msg)
        self.code = code
        self.msg = msg
```

create a custom page "error.html" that show only err_code err_msg and request or raison if you want.
"{{err_code}} {{err_msg}} {{request}}"

dont miss to add the template in your settings.py in template

create a middleware
EXAMPLE:

```
class JobMiddlewareException:
    def process_exception(self, request, e):
       if isinstance(e, HTTPError)
            render_to_response('error.html', {'err_code': e.code, 'err_msg': e.msg, 'request':request}, requestcontext(request))
```

EXAMPLE:
and in your code when you need to raise error you do

> Raise HTTPError(404, 'Not Found. the page is not valid for user %s' %
>   request.user)

Comment: i miss to add you should test after that in unittest with assertRaise(404, method, code='code')